# boto error to launch ec2 instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ansible

i am using ansible to create an ec2 isntance . during the playbook run, i am getting the error as:

```
TASK [create a single ec2 instance] ********************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: NameError: name 'botocore' is not defined
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_eVkiMV/ansible_module_ec2.py\", line 1554, in <module>\n    from ansible.module_utils.ec2 import *\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_eVkiMV/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/ec2.py\", line 61, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_eVkiMV/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/ec2.py\", line 62, in AWSRetry\nNameError: name 'botocore' is not defined\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE"}
        to retry, use: --limit @apache_aws.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

it says that botocore is not defined but i installed boto using pip install boto. can anyone please figure out what problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install boto3 (`pip install boto3`)